# What's the meaning of "whatever you are, you are woman"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, zero-article

> Whatever you are, you
>   are woman.

In the first look the meaning of the phrase seems clear, but it's hard to get. I wonder why the writer didn't say, "whatever you are, you are *a* woman.

Could you plaese help me to understand it's meaning?

The main text is here:

> I carried the books to my room and read through the night. I loved the
>   fiery pages of Mary Wollstonecraft, but there was a single line written by
>   John Stuart Mill that, when I read it, moved the world: “It is a subject on
>   which nothing final can be known.” The subject Mill had in mind was the
>   nature of women. Mill claimed that women have been coaxed, cajoled,
>   shoved and squashed into a series of feminine contortions for so many
>   centuries, that it is now quite impossible to define their natural abilities or
>   aspirations.
>   Blood rushed to my brain; I felt an animating surge of adrenaline, of
>   possibility, of a frontier being pushed outward. Of the nature of women,
>   nothing final can be known. Never had I found such comfort in a void, in
>   the black absence of knowledge. It seemed to say: **whatever you are, you
>   are woman**.

Comment: I think some of your questions aren't really about learning English (you're trying to interpret what the author means). Try asking these questions at https://literature.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Peace, Note that duplicate questions are considered a no-no on the Stack Exchange. Read through the Tour and Help Center (every exchange has a "What topics can I ask about here?" page) of both places, and figure out the best place to ask. @userr2684291 - I'm not sure I agree with your assessment. Is this a question about "how to interpret a specific scene, quote, theme, plot point, etc. in a work of literature?" Not really; it's about the meaning of a single sentence extracted from a novel's paragraph.

Comment: @ J.R. I apologise. I didn't know that. I prefer I ask the question here.So I deleted it at literature.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I am not going to give an answer because I do not see that there is one. Whatever meaning the author intended, the reader will have to intuit it. **Whatever you are, you are woman** is contradictory on its face. If what you are is unknown, then it cannot be known that you are a woman. And **you are woman** is either ungrammatical or a statement that women are not individuals. Novelists and poets are allowed to say things that each reader can interpret in his or her own way.

Comment: @J.R. "How to interpret a specific ... quote ... in a work of literature" – yes, that's it. Thank you for finding the pertinent "rule". Just look at the accepted answer here; it's impossible to answer this without inserting one's own opinion or something. Also take a look at Jeff Morrow's comment.

Comment: @userr2684291 - There's a difference between "I don't get this because I don't understand what profundity this author is trying to express," and "I don't get this because I am a novice at English and I don't understand the nuances of the language." Sometimes a question (like this one) can be a little bit of both, but I don't think it's good practice to insist that a English [learner](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/74396/peace?tab=questions) go ask their question at a literature site simply because there happens to be a modicum of literary analysis in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is converting woman into a proper noun (I think)

Imagine the sentence "whatever you are, you are Julie". This makes sense.

It is raising the importance of woman above the humdrum everyday into something special. A woman can be a million things but she is still a Woman, still a member of that special group.

I presume you are discussing this:
https://www.tolstoytherapy.com/2018/05/educated-by-tara-westover-and-how.html